# Websphere Runtime transaction timeout problem

Tags: java, spring, jboss, transactions, websphere

We use two application server ,Jboss and Websphere (v8.5.5.11).
We are using jboss in local platform but development server uses Websphere.I want to change transaction timeout on runtime .On Jboss works fine but websphere not.How can I set transaction timeout for websphere's thread.

```
JtaTransactionManager  tm = (JtaTransactionManager) SpringApplicationContext.getContext().getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class);
tm.getUserTransaction().setTransactionTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of obtaining the WebSphere Application Server transaction manager in order to set the transaction timeout (in seconds) on a thread,

```
com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionManagerFactory.getTransactionManager().setTransactionTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: I add this dependency and try this code but not work, my flow like this every soap request is recieved one bean , and this bean know what run class method's like request header. and set transaction time on runtime.I want to change timeout every method runs dynamically. the above line of code works on jboss , but not work websphere.

Comment: Is it possible that the transaction was already started when you invoke this code? If so, it won't help - it would only apply to the next transaction on the thread.

Comment: we are defining transaction timeout before when we invoke this code .important point is that, we use CMT , not BTM, maybe it helps to your advice

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Then the container would have already started the transaction and so the setTransactionTimeout API is being invoked too late to help.  There must be a difference between app servers here as to whether a transaction timeout can be applied retroactively to an existing transaction.  Is it possible for you to switch to application/bean managed transactions?
```
UserTransaction tran = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
tran.setTransactionTimeout(timeout);
tran.begin();
...
tran.commit();
```

Comment: The main logic of the project is to act as a gateway. According to the requests that come with the soap, to call certain methods on a single bean in runtime. We determine the transaction timeout in the runtime for the methods we call. We cannot determine the risk of this as BMT. So we have to use CMT. We can do this for JBOSS TJA.getUserTransaction.setTimeout (). I tried using the code you said for Was, but timeout doesn't work